# How do I add my .h files if they are in different directory?

Tags: c++

```
#include <Dao/Dao.h>
#include <Cola/Cola.h>
int main(){return 0;}
```

I am trying to compile that code with this makefile:

```
DIR = -I/usr/include/cppconn -I/home/panda/Documents/eclipse-workspace/Computacion/Cola -I/home/panda/Documents/eclipse-workspace/Computacion/Dao
main: main.o Dao.o Cola.o Nodo.o
        $(CXX) -Wall $(DIR) -o main main.o Dao.o Cola.o Nodo.o -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn
```

It works perfectly when I take Dao.h and Cola.h to the same directory the main file is in

Output of make:

```
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:2:21: fatal error: Dao/Dao.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: It has to be in the same working directory, otherwise youll need to go up by one directory using `...` notation

Comment: `-I/home/panda/Documents/eclipse-workspace/Computacion/Cola` says look in directory blah/Computacion/Cola. The C file is looking for <Cola/Cola.h>, so what would be searched is blah/Computacion/Cola/Cola/Cola.h. `-I/home/panda/Documents/eclipse-workspace/Computacion` should give you the path you need.

Comment: Do you have two directories in a row named Cola and Dao? If not, your include paths are incorrect, they need to point the the directory where the Cola and Dao directories are if you plan to include the directory name in your includes. You also may want to use quotes instead of `<>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
DIR = -I/usr/include/cppconn -I/home/panda/Documents/eclipse-workspace/Computacion
```

since your `#include` statements already specify `Dao` and `Cola`. So you need to add the parent directory of `Dao` and `Cola` in your build flags.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the directory paths to the object files because they are in a different directory than the makefile.

```
DIR = -I/usr/include/cppconn -I/home/panda/Documents/eclipse-workspace/Computacion
OBJS = main.o ./Dao/Dao.o ./Cola/Cola.o ./Cola/Nodo.o ./Persona/Persona.o
main: $(OBJS)
g++ -Wall $(DIR) $(OBJS) -o main -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn
```